# Is there any way to stop loading mapbox gl layer?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

In my app i have usecases when after adding tile layer on hybrid styled map user can quickly switch to roadmap styled map without previous layer. If tile layer doesn't begin loading, it will be rendered on roadmap.
So I need to stop loading tile layer or have some listener, that fires when layer is loaded. Tried solve this problem by using `removeLayer` method but it doesn't help. Want to avoid using `setTimeout` or any async js method if there any solution in Mapbox gl library.

Sorry, code is private. For example I have some method in my class that switch from one style to another when clicking on button. If satellite then layer is drawn, otherwise it is removed. Tried both deleting and hiding.

```
const map = new mapboxgl.Map();

const drawLayer = (layerId: string) => {
   map.addSource(`${layerId}-source`, {
         'type': 'raster',
         'tiles': [getTileUrl()],
         'tileSize': 256
       });
   map.addLayer({
        'id': layerId,
        'type': 'raster',
        'source': `${layerId}-source`,
        'paint': {
          'raster-opacity': opacity
        }
      });
};

const switchStyle = (isSatellite: boolean) => {
   if (isSatellite) {
      map.setOptions({
         styles = 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-streets-v10'
      });
      drawLayer('some-layer-id');
   } else {
      map.setOptions({
         styles = 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'
      });
      if (map.getLayer('some-layer-id')) {
         map.removeLayer('some-layer-id');
         map.removeSource('some-layer-id-source');
      }
   }
}

map.once('load', () => {
  document.getElementById("switchButton").addEventListener("click", switchStyle);
});
```

Comment: Please add relevant code.

Comment: @MurliPrajapati there is example that somekind similar to my code

Comment: @MurliPrajapati sry, do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you post a minimum reproducible example on jsFiddle/codepen/jsbin?